# zeromq.node installation error Ubuntu 12.04: ' node-gyp rebuild'

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, zeromq, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to install [zeromq.node](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node) using:

`$ npm install zmq`

However, I keep getting the error below. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:215:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:91:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:674:10)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-29-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/share/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/robot/code/game/node_modules/zmq
gyp ERR! node -v v0.8.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.6.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! zmq@2.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the zmq@2.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the zmq package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls zmq
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-29-generic
npm ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "zmq"
npm ERR! cwd /home/robot/code/game/test/amqp
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.6
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.48
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/robot/code/game/test/amqp/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: 'Additional logging details can be found in: home/robot/code/game/test/amqp/npm-debug.log'. This file should contains full error description. Post it here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

gyp bulid error removed libzmq dev and its dependencies and tried below steps..it worked for me

```
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get install build-essential
 $ sudo apt-get install libzmq-dev
 $ npm install zmq
```

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve this by following [this tutorial for installing the python-client.](http://ridingpython.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/installing-zeromq-python-lib-pyzmq-on.html) After completing each of the steps I found I was then able to install the node.zeromq module through npm using:

```
$ npm install zmq
```

I'm guessing this is due to missing some of the required files. Most likely `libzmq-dev`.

Comment: This one http://stackoverflow.com/a/23732646/30946 was more helpful. There's no good reason to install python stuff to fix node tools.