# Force npm compiling packages using docker image

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker, npm, compilation

I'm trying to start a Docker with an Ubuntu image and the installing zmq from npm.
It seems that when it executes the `npm install` it uses the kernel from my computer (Arch Linux 4.8.13) to compile the packages.

How could I force to use the image Ubuntu in the docker to compile the packages of the npm?

I let you here a screenshot with the result of the build and the Dockerfile

[image: Result of executing docker-compose build]

This is the content of `/var/www/forum/npm-debug.log`

```
> zmq@2.15.3 install /var/www/forum/node_modules/zmq
> node-gyp rebuild

/bin/sh: 1: node: not found
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:354:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit(internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.8.13-1-ARCH
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/forum/node_modules/zmq
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN forum-sad@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN forum-sad@0.0.1 No license field.
npm ERR! Linux 4.8.13-1-ARCH
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! zmq@2.15.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the zmq@2.15.3 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the zmq package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs zmq
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls zmq
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/forum/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Next time paste the content of the Dockerfile instead of a screenshot. Paste also the content of the `var/www/forum/npm-debug.log` it may give some hints.

Comment: Okey! Pasted...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [zeromq.node installation error Ubuntu 12.04: ' node-gyp rebuild'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975983/zeromq-node-installation-error-ubuntu-12-04-node-gyp-rebuild)

Comment: The error was that it was be created a symbolic link from nodejs to node before. Thank for the help!